# What is the difference between "On n'y connaissait pas grand-chose" and "On ne connaissait pas grand-chose" ?

Tags: pronoms

> « On n'y connaissait pas grand-chose à l'époque. »
>
> vs « On ne connaissait pas grand-chose à l'époque. »

I wonder what purpose it serves to inlude the word "**y**" in this sentence. Is it for emphasis on negation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*y*, which is a pronoun, will there refer to a specific topic, while the second sentence is more vague.

> On parle beaucoup de technologies. On n'y connaissait pas grand chose à l'époque.

In this sentence, you're saying that, back in the time, you didn't know much about technology, because *y* refers to *technologies*. You could replace *y* by *ne ... à celà*.

> On parle beaucoup de technologies. On ne connaissait pas grand chose à cela à l'époque.

For the second sentence :

> On ne connaissait pas grand chose à l'époque.

There, if there is no more context, you're simply saying :

> We didn't know much about stuff in general at that time.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I understand that the pronoun "y" replaces a previous "à ..." phrase. I was stumped because I thought that the verb "connaître" is a  transitive verb and, as such, cannot take the form of "connaître à quelque chose". I didn't know that "à cela" can be used here.

Comment: As it was the answer you were looking for, do not forget to accept the answer ! :)